# Javascript (or some other lang) to detect the wheel direction without using pageYOffset

Tags: javascript, mousewheel, scroller

I have a page not higher than the window => it has no scroller.

How can I detect the direction, in which the wheel is rolled?

And if JavaScript can't handle this, is there some other net language to help my case?

Thanks

Comment: First result of Google search provides the answer: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/

Comment: Be careful with using physical devices, you may want to detect actions instead. For example, scrolling can be done with the wheel, gestures, keyboard or dragging a scroll bar. The wheel is used for zooming, scrolling, panning or other UI actions in combination with modifier keys that may not be consistent in different hosts (and may depend on user settings unavailable to script).

Answer (score 2):

It's given to you wholesale on the [MDN page for "wheel" events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Listening_to_this_event_across_browser), reproduced below:

```
(function(window,document) {

    var prefix = "", _addEventListener, onwheel, support;

    // detect event model
    if ( window.addEventListener ) {
        _addEventListener = "addEventListener";
    } else {
        _addEventListener = "attachEvent";
        prefix = "on";
    }

    // detect available wheel event
    support = "onwheel" in document.createElement("div") ? "wheel" : // Modern browsers support "wheel"
              document.onmousewheel !== undefined ? "mousewheel" : // Webkit and IE support at least "mousewheel"
              "DOMMouseScroll"; // let's assume that remaining browsers are older Firefox

    window.addWheelListener = function( elem, callback, useCapture ) {
        _addWheelListener( elem, support, callback, useCapture );

        // handle MozMousePixelScroll in older Firefox
        if( support == "DOMMouseScroll" ) {
            _addWheelListener( elem, "MozMousePixelScroll", callback, useCapture );
        }
    };

    function _addWheelListener( elem, eventName, callback, useCapture ) {
        elem[ _addEventListener ]( prefix + eventName, support == "wheel" ? callback : function( originalEvent ) {
            !originalEvent && ( originalEvent = window.event );

            // create a normalized event object
            var event = {
                // keep a ref to the original event object
                originalEvent: originalEvent,
                target: originalEvent.target || originalEvent.srcElement,
                type: "wheel",
                deltaMode: originalEvent.type == "MozMousePixelScroll" ? 0 : 1,
                deltaX: 0,
                deltaZ: 0,
                preventDefault: function() {
                    originalEvent.preventDefault ?
                        originalEvent.preventDefault() :
                        originalEvent.returnValue = false;
                }
            };

            // calculate deltaY (and deltaX) according to the event
            if ( support == "mousewheel" ) {
                event.deltaY = - 1/40 * originalEvent.wheelDelta;
                // Webkit also support wheelDeltaX
                originalEvent.wheelDeltaX && ( event.deltaX = - 1/40 * originalEvent.wheelDeltaX );
            } else {
                event.deltaY = originalEvent.detail;
            }

            // it's time to fire the callback
            return callback( event );

        }, useCapture || false );
    }

})(window,document);
```

Then you can:

```
addWheelListener( document, function( e ) { 
    console.log( e.deltaY < 0 ? "up" : "down" ); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
} );
```

Comment: In the second code you added - where should I add the function in case the wheel is up and in case it is down?

Thanks and sorry for my not-understanding.

Comment: What is the point of passing in *window* and *document*? The code should also look for modifier keys, since the wheel + modifier may be used for zooming.

Comment: @RobG You should ask that to the person who contributed the code to MDN! It certainly looks redundant. If you're 100% convinced then MDN operates as a Wiki, so you could [update the code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/users/signin?next=/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel%24edit) if it grates.

Comment: I didn't realise you'd just copy/pasted the code. I spend a bit of time here and there updating MDN, but writing good code takes time and research and I'm not sure a wheel event is very useful, particularly given its non–standardised behaviour and complexity. Per my comment above, coding for physical features is risky, if not fraught.

Comment: @RobG Agreed. Issues around this kind of thing can be very subtle.