# Javascript detect scroll wheel movement without actually scrolling

Tags: javascript

I have a Website on which you cant scroll down, but I would like the user to be able to scroll to trigger an event. Any Ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `mousewheel` event?

Comment: trigger an event = call a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a `wheel` event. `mousewheel` events are deprecated. You want something like this, of course:

```
_addWheelListener = function( wheelEvent ) { // Warning
    console.log(wheelEvent);                 // Does not work!
}
```

It's important to note that `wheel` events seem to be treated *very* differently based on what browser and/or browser version your users are on. So you will want to be very careful about what you put inside the `wheelListener` function.

[Fortunately, someone at MZDN has done the heavy lifting for us](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Browser_compatibility)

Once you copy paste their function into your javascript, you can define a `wheelListener` as follows:

```
addWheelListener(document, function( wheelEvent ) {
    console.log(wheelEvent);
});
```

Comment: Is there an option to find out the direction you scroll in?

Comment: [Yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Properties), you can track deltaX, deltaY, and even deltaZ

Comment: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335608/javascript-or-some-other-lang-to-detect-the-wheel-direction-without-using-page) does a better job of explaining the exact process of adding the wheelListener. I encourage you to look here. @Teiem

Answer (score 0):

Listening to the `wheel` event:

```js
addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
    console.log("wheeling", e)
});
```

```html
<div height="200vh"></div>
```